# Backbone.js vs PHP, jQuery Mobile website

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I recently discovered Backbone.js and decided to learn it to build a single page mobile website at work. This website relies mostly on data from a remote JSON API (e.g. http://domain.com/players/username = {name: 'username', ...}).

I figure I can build a single page mobile site using jQuery Mobile and PHP with a well-structured MVC directory and use jQuery's .load() to pull PHP/html files dynamically. Would there be any benefit of using Backbone.js over PHP with a custom MVC structure mixed with JavaScript?

I started using Backbone.js and apparently now I need to use CORS because the API runs off a different domain and it's just starting to get complicated.

What's your opinion? I assume with PHP I might have both .php and .js constrollers and views so I don't know if that's bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server running the API doesn't have CORS enabled, then you will have to have some sort of backend to handle the requests for you. Depending on the complexity, you will not need to have both PHP and JS views/controllers/models. My suggestion is to have PHP controllers that relay your requests to the server and route the response back to the client. The PHP code would be acting as a sort of middle-man between your JS and the API you are using.

Comment: Right, so I can ignore Backbone.js and just use jQuery and jQuery Mobile? I just want to know if I'm wasting time using Backbone.js. I need to do account authentication and many other data heavy stuff and I feel it will get unnecessarily complex with Backbone.js.

Comment: Backbone.js can make your code unnecessarily complex if you use it incorrectly, but if you're looking to make a single page app, it might still be the way you want to go. It's a good way to keep your data organized. I would use Backbone models to have a simple interface to the server i.e. having methods on the model for show/edit/delete/index which would hit their respective server endpoints. Of course it's personal preference, but I would use Angular since I find it more natural than Backbone

Comment: I read that Angular.js had a higher learning curve than Backbone.js, but I'll give it a second look. I will be using PHP for fetching and outputting JSON data ad JavaScript for the rest. In other words, make a local directory with PHP files that just return JSON data from the remote API using cURL.

Comment: Angular probably is more difficult to learn, especially structurally. But it sounds like the rest is pretty straight-forward and you have the right idea.